# How to programmatically set the dropped control rect of a CComboBox

Tags: mfc, combobox, drop-down-menu

How to programmatically set the dropped control rect of a CComboBox?

I know I can do this in the resource editor, but how do I change it, or set it if I programmatically create a combo box?

I can acquire this information via the CB_GETDROPPEDCONTROLRECT message, but I don't see a corresponding set message/function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just use SetWindowPos and set the size in the cy parameter (with SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE set).  cx does need to be set correctly though.